# Create new folder in shared folder(windows file sharing) in windows 7 using webclient

Tags: c#, windows-7, webclient, ftpwebrequest, file-sharing

I want to create/delete a folder in a Windows 7 network sharing folder. I can create/delete folder just fine using windows explorer. I can download file from the folder just fine using c# webclient. But since there is no method to create/delete folder in webclient, i cant create/delete folder using webclient. is there a way to create/delete folder in a windows 7 shared folder using webclient? or i should use ftpwebrequest?

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a network shared folder then you should be able to use the standard libraries for creating files/folders without any networking code. Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as2f1fez.aspx) for instruction on how to create folders. Let's say the folder is on a networked machine called COMPUTER, then you'd do something like

```
public class CreateFileOrFolder
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string activeDir = @"\\COMPUTER";
        string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(activeDir, "myNewFolder");

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! No wonder i cant find it, its not in network namespace. By the way, how can i use it in password protected shared folder? Thanks.